# Applying span on a string in react returns [object Object] instead of giving me the spanned text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to apply span on certain words in a sentence.

```
return "hello how are you hello".replace(/hello|you/gi, <span className="some-class">"new"</span>);
```

In my view I see [object Object] instead of (span)new(span) how are (span)new(span) (span)new(span)

I have tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML too but no luck. I still get [object Object]

Comment: Your missing quotes in the `replace` function around the `<span>`, but as React supports HTML directly in the JS you should probably post the entire function that generates the view. You most likely want those missing quotes, to return a string, anything else would make little sense.

Comment: To add to adeneo's comment: I got it working by adding the quotes to the `<span>` tag in the `replace` function, and render it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.replace` returns a string, so it's converting your `React.createElement` call into the string `[object Object]`.

Instead you might want to split your sentence up into words, map over them and returning jsx if it matches your regex, otherwise returning the string.

```
var stringArray = "hello how are you hello".split(" ")
var regex = /hello|you/i
var elements = stringArray.map(string =>
  regex.test(string) ? <span>{ string }</span> : string
)

render() {
  return <div>{ elements }</div>
}
```

Comment: The only reason I did not split my sentence into words is, sometimes my regex is a phrase and not necessarily a word.

Comment: Ah yes, well the general idea still applies. You can parse your string into chunks with the regex first, you could even have an array of `{ string: '', matches: true }`